# e.e. cummings User Badge -- Feature Request

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

When:

A user posts an upvoted question that:

1. Uses no Upper Case characters, especially avoiding "I" for the personal pronoun.
2. otherwise contains punctuation in non-code blocks; and
3. "grammar" is not a substring of any edit reasons attached to the question

the user earns an `ee cummings badge`, in honor of the [famous poet Edward Estlin Cummings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings), who was known to write in this lowercase style.

I think this would be a bronze badge.

The badge could also provide a polite request not to write in this style, generally.

I realize most badges are awarded for good behaviors, but there is also the `peer-pressure` badge, which suggests at least a slight twinge of misbehavior involved.

**ADDENDUM** If you can't tell, this proposal was not entirely serious.  I do wish that long unpunctuated posts in lower case would be blocked with greater frequency, and that it was more difficult for an OP with low reputation to roll back community approved edits.

Comment: How about we make that a "you've been banned" badge, coming with an actual ban? :)

Comment: I'm sure that exists somewhere

Comment: Tumbleweed is also a sort of negative badge. Peer pressure is doing something good (after doing something bad)

Comment: Definitely not good for your Careers profile.

Comment: Might be funny on April Fool's, otherwise is just annoying.

Comment: Must admit it's very original idea, but simply does not fit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, if this is so hated, can we at least block questions that have multiple lines of all lower case text and no punctuation.  I'm trying to get that `Steward` badge and I might need to take a break.

Comment: Do we really need more posts written like that?

Comment: @Richard Tingle: True, but Tumbleweed badges are not necessarily due to the lack of question-asking skills (e.g. the question requires specialized problem-domain knowledge). An e.e. cummings badge awarded in the manner suggested by the OP would only be due to incompetence.

Comment: @user137487 the automatic quality filter does attempt to catch most of these.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well there's a lot that make it to the review edits queue.  I fixed someone's post tonight and, subsequently, they rolled it all back.

Comment: @user137487 it's not perfect but it does do it's job as you often see people complaining on meta about why they can submit their poorly formatted uncapitalized question

Comment: New downvote today! >3 years and still going strong.  Hooray!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I realize most badges are awarded for good behaviors, but there is also the peer-pressure badge, which suggests at least a slight twinge of misbehavior involved.

*All* badges are designed to encourage and reward positive behaviors. The Peer Pressure badge is awarded for deleting a post with a score of -3 or lower. That *is* positive behavior—removing noise from the site. Most answers do not reach a score of -3 unless they are spam, completely incorrect, or utterly useless. All of those are good reasons to delete an answer outright. If you make this call yourself and save someone else the effort, we reward that with a badge.

> the user earns an ee cummings badge, in honor of the famous poet Edward Estlin Cummings, who was known to write in this lowercase style.

e e cummings was known for a lot more than writing in all lowercase. In particular, he was a *brilliant* poet and artist in general. The Wikipedia article, in a deviation from its typical all-business style, even waxes eloquent about him being "remembered as an eminent voice of 20th century poetry".

Yes, he used a style that could be described as "avant garde", but that is…not an adequate description of the types of posts that our quality filter catches.

To award an e e cummings badge to people who post poorly-formatted, low-quality content to Stack Exchange sites would be an *insult* to Mr Cummings and his legacy.

Seriously, do we really want to *encourage* users to post crap like this just to earn a badge?

Comment: Of course not.  I just wish they would stop.

Comment: @user So why not just block their submissions? Why should we award them a badge?

Comment: @user137487: How would awarding a badge help make them not write crap posts?

Comment: If you catch it early, and correct it with humor instead of punishment, it might salvage some people.

Comment: I don't know about that. I laugh every time I downvote questions like this. It hasn't seemed to stem the tide.

Comment: People who write crappy posts are very unlikely to catch the reference. A badge is a badge, and *many* people just want to collect them all. Awarding a badge for poorly formatted posts would only mean that there would be more poorly formatted posts.

Answer (score 4):

No.

This badge would encourage bad behaviour.

The peer-pressure badge does not encourage bad behavior, it encourages people to remove rubbish posts.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, badges are supposed to encourage positive behavior or teach a user about the features of the times, and this badge will not encourage either.  In fact it will cause more harm as people will intentionally write bad posts to get it.

Your assertion that `Peer Pressure` is a negative badge is incorrect.  While people do intentionally write poor questions to get it, there is more positive that comes out of it as it teaches someone how to delete a post (and since the post gets deleted, we don't have to deal with the intentionally written poor quality post so the impact to the site in minimal).

I would say `Tumbleweed` is closer to a badge with no really purpose and bordering on a negative badge, but it is long been viewed as a "We're sorry no-one wanted to look at your question, so here is a cookie" type badge.  It is also extremely difficult to intentionally try to get due to the requirements, so you do not have a lot of negative impact to the site because of it.